# Is the structure "would + subject + have" in non-interrogative sentences possible?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I was writing a short story and realized I made a mistake using "would + have". At first, I tried writing the sentence like the one below but then realized the subject had to go after would. For some reason, it didn't seem like such a mistake, even though it is. I would like to know if there are instances where it is possible to use a similar structure and if anyone can enlighten me regarding this topic.

1. Julia found herself stranded without a phone at night. Only then (at that moment) would she have wished she had listened to her mother.

I want to emphasize that, at that moment, Julia realized that she should have listened to her mother. She wishes she had listened to her mother so she would not have to be in that situation. What would be the best way to write that? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: This may get closed as "proofreading" or "find the errors in my sentence", but "would she have wished" isn't correct here because it sounds like a hypothetical, which isn't what you mean.  You just mean only at that moment *did* she wish it.

Comment: @stangdon I think the OP's concern is specific enough to not be closed as such.